# RestKit with CoreData crashes

Tags: core-data, ios5, restkit

I am new to CoreData and just started working with RestKit. I am trying to create a Restkit project with CoreData. But I am getting this runtime error:

Assertion failure in +[NSManagedObject managedObjectContext]

Any ideas, what I am doing wrong?

Following is my code so far. I have not created a data model as of now.

```
     _objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues"];
  //  _objectManager.objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"jiffAssignment.sqlite"];

    RKManagedObjectMapping *locationMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Location class]];
    [locationMapping mapKeyPath:@"address" toAttribute:@"address"];
    [locationMapping mapKeyPath:@"crossStreet" toAttribute:@"crossStreet"];
    [locationMapping mapKeyPath:@"city" toAttribute:@"city"];
    [locationMapping mapKeyPath:@"state" toAttribute:@"state"];
    [_objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:locationMapping forKeyPath:@"location"];

  //  RKObjectMapping *statisticsMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Statistics class]];
 //   [statisticsMapping mapAttributes:@"checkinsCount",@"usersCount", nil];


    NSLog(@"VenueListController Initialized");
    return self;
```

Any help/comments would be appreciated.

Thanks
Vik

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your post with the actual assertion that fails?

And you shouldn't be able to use an `RKManagedObjectMapping` if `_objectManager` doesn't have an `objectStore` set. This line is commented out in the code you posted.